# Database Design: Modeling Bridge Tables

Tags: postgresql, database-design, facttable

Team: I have a question regarding a requirement: One security officer works can work at many offices. Depending on the office that the security officer is working on that day, the officer can have a different role.

So: I have modeled the entities as follows: *Officers*; *Offices*; and *Roles*. My questions / request for advice is that I have currently modeled this requirement in the database with a bridge table: *Officers_Offices_Roles_Bridge* that has a composite key: *officer_id*, *office_id*, and *role_id*.

For example, an officer working in the Manhattan office on Mondays has junior security specialist role, and working in the Bronx office on Tuesdays has dispatcher role.

I wanted to know whether having a bridge table between three (or more) tables a reasonable strategy? Are there alternative approaches to requirements of this sort that would be more efficient?

Please let me know if you require any additional information. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

While there's nothing wrong with "a bridge table between three (or more) tables", looking at

> the office that the security officer is working on that day

the "on that day", in combination with "can have a different role", suggests that, instead of a typical bridge/junction table you have here a separate entity, *OfficerShiftSchedule* or something, with the attributes of *officer*, *office*, and *role*, via the respective IDs, and the shift date (or start and end time).